# How to draw schematic and set values for transformer with auxiliary winding in LTSpice simulation software?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice

I have drawn the [schematic](https://1fichier.com/?izw3imh9aa) in LTSpice for dc to dc buck converter in LTSpice. I want transformer with auxiliary winding.At the secondary side , I want Vout=5V and Iout=2A . The auxiliary winding is required to supply 5V to the UCC28C40. Winding ratio is given as \$\sqrt{L1}\$:\$\sqrt{L2} =N1:N2\$ .

I think that N1=120 and N2=7, N3=6. So values of inductor should be L1=14400 ,L2=49 and L3=36 .Also, I have set the values of peak current of L1 as 0.387A and L2 as 8.18A. But when I click on **RUN** button ,It gives error as  "missing value for I1". So  are values written using **spice directive** i.e. "k1 L2 L1 L3 1"  right or wrong? Also, what changes should I do in the schematic ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your inductors, but with your I1 current source.

Comment: @PlasmaHH  but I have set the values of peak current of L1 and L2 .then also it is giving the above error

Comment: PlasmaHH is right. I'm curious about what you plan to to do with the current source (I1) at the output section. Delete it. Also, don't forget to put a load resistor (e.g. 1k) across the output capacitor, because it's necessary for a flyback converter to operate normally.

Comment: @user3559780: how do you think the settings of I1 get magically adjusted by playing with L1 and L2 ?

Comment: @RohatKılıç but sir ,given design  is obtained from the texas instrument's [webench software](http://webench.ti.com/)

Comment: @user3559780 Are you sure that it's a current source? I think it should be an ammeter. Anyway, delete it, put a load resistor across the output capacitor and run again.

Comment: A current source at the output simplifies a hand-calculation or the presentation of that webench simulation but it's quite difficult to get your simulation started with it in LTspice. Also, one node is unconnected to it in your example. Delete it and replace with a resistor.